# Link to PDF in Careers profile editor

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, jobs

Today I was looking to generate a fresh copy of my CV, only to discover that I couldn't find the link for generating a PDF or printing a copy. I noticed that the profile editor was redone in the (recent?) past, and I thought I remembered the old editor having the PDF/print links available in the right sidebar.

Right now in order to export your CV you need to go to "Profile settings" in the right column

[image: The link to the "Profile settings" button]

And then you will see the export options available in the right column, where they might have been in the past.

[image: The export options are in the right column]

I never remembered it taking this much effort to export my CV in the past. Can we add the links for exporting your CV within the new profile editor?

Answer (score -10):

I'm the developer that worked on the changes here. This is actually by design. We want to encourage people to share their online public profile rather than exporting a PDF version of it when possible. Of course, we still allow for this capability to account for systems that still require a PDF be uploaded or sent, and it's only one extra click away.

Comment: I don't agree, you've just moved the cheese around and made it harder to find. It's like placing the downvote arrow behind some other, non related link, to encourage more upvotes.

Comment: Encouraging people by making the interface less useful is an interesting design decision.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz it happens allll the time. How much bikeshedding have we seen on SO close reasons?

Comment: This is the worst design decision I've ever heard of. Honestly, careers is basically useful for this specific purpose (to keep an up-to-date cv and easily export it). Damn.

Comment: OOOH! This design follows the [leopard principle](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/40705-but-the-plans-were-on-display-on-display-i-eventually)

Comment: @Jon Chan - Really?  You're the developer of this and you think placing the print option or the export option of a frigging resume should be under settings ?  What settings are you changing with this?  0, zilch, none, nada,  did I mention zero?  Please change this to actually make sense.  Someone wanting a spit out of the pdf should reach no further than the top right corner with a shiny export button right there.  Your answer only confuses the end user.

Comment: The issue here isn't just that this feature is viewed as desirable, it is also placed badly. It's kind of like leaving all of the knives in a drawer named "spoons". Even if you argued "the food is cut to bite-size" the knives do not belong in the spoon drawer.

Comment: The more I think about this, the more I wonder about this decision. This is akin to hiding the headlights switch in the car. You might protest, "but it has running lights, there is never a time when they should have the lights off", but that assumes that you know all potential use cases (which you DON'T)