# Can no Longer Find Convert to PDF Option

Tags: support, jobs, pdf

There used to be an option to convert my Stack Overflow careers profile to a PDF file, which is a great feature.

However, I can no longer find an option to do this. Was it removed?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Let's close \[jobs\] questions!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/377689/lets-close-jobs-questions)

Comment: (The [Jobs tag wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/jobs/info) could be updated.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The profile editor was redone and the 'create pdf' was moved. As per the "[Link to PDF in Careers profile editor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/262212/link-to-pdf-in-careers-profile-editor)" feature-request: (emphasis is mine)

> Right now in order to **export your CV** you need to go to "**Profile
>   settings**" in the right column
>
> And then you will see the **export options** available in the **right column**, where they might have been in the past.

This feature request was *declined* and you can read Jon Chan's answer on the post.

Comment: Ah yes, there it is. I was going to comment that this is not as convenient or intuitive as where it was before, but I see that was the point of the change, as stackoverflow career's goal is to keep the profile online.

Comment: @JonathanWood yes and that's the reason for [status-declined] on that feature-request