# Can no longer find 'Export to PDF' feature in Careers page

Tags: support, status-norepro, jobs

The Export to PDF link that was moved is not visible when going to "Profile Settings" as described in a [related question about this feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/262212/link-to-pdf-in-careers-profile-editor).

Comment: It's working just fine for me. If you're still seeing this problem, could you please update your question with more details about the steps you tried (and browser/OS info), along with screenshots?